# DownLoad Data from server with "Pause" and "Resume" functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I want to download a file with pause/resume functionality. I read apple documents, there I got  `NSUrldownload` which supports the same but it is not available for iOS. I was trying with  `NSUrlconnection`, but not working. **I don't want to use any third party libraries, I want to implement it by myself, below is the code snippet which I tried**.

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~%@",[[url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]];

int dataLength = [[self checkDocDirectoryforFileName:fileName] length];
//dataLength = 0;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setValue:@"audio/mpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"bytes" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Ranges"];
[request setValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dataLength] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSLog(@"Request header  %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: If you want to implement it by yourself check the source code of AFDownloadRequestOperation, it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS 7.0 and above

**NSURLSession** especially **NSURLSessionDownloadTask**  provides this functionality.

> The NSURLSession API provides status and progress properties, in
>   addition to delivering this information to delegates. It supports
>   canceling, restarting or resuming, and suspending tasks, and it
>   provides the ability to resume suspended, canceled, or failed
>   downloads where they left off.

[Take a look to the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

### iOS 5.0 and above

I would use [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) for this. [Take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173744/afnetworking-pause-resume-downloading-big-files).

> AFDownloadRequestOperation has
>   additional support to resume a partial download, uses a temporary
>   directory and has a special block that helps with calculating the
>   correct download progress.

Comment: Thanks. But `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` both are available for iOS 7.0 and later. Is it possible for below iOS 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

Please check it out this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839-SW2

Hope, May it will help you,

:)

Comment: It is using `NSURLDownload`, which is not available for iOS.